# Is it possible to incorporate html events with java?

Tags: java, html, events, event-handling

```html
<input type='file' onchange='<% do java code %>'/>
```

I will call the java function to upload file to server once file is changed. Is this possible? If so what do I do to do it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not possible, however you can make [a XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and create a request handler on server side to accomplish this.

Comment: Aniket Sahrawet if you answer this question I will tick your answer, thanks!